# append RSA signature to a text file

Tags: c, rsa, aes, digital-signature

I have a text file that I have to sign with RSA private key and then append this signature and do an AES encryption over this "text file+signature".

For demonstration reasons I am testing such an encrypted file.

I am writing a simple program in C to do the following:
First do an RSA sign(1024 bit) on a text file.
Then append the signature to the text file
Then do an AES encryption over the file.

Then perform the AES decryption
Then remove the 128 byte signature from the file.
Then do an RSA verification of the original text file and the text file after decryption.

Here are my questions:

Is it a good idea to append a binary signature to a text file?
If no what is the general way this is done?

I tried a simple program to do the above but I always get one or two junk characters on AES decryption and therefore RSA verification fails.

Do please suggest.
an AES decrypt of such a file and then remove the 128 byte(1024 bit modulus) signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ad-hoc standard for embedding crypto information in text files was introduced by [Privacy Enhanced Mail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_Enhanced_Mail) some time ago: Basically the binary information is encoded in base-64 and appended to the text file along with a header line to identify the "snip" point for the added content.

Here is a sample of what it typically looks like (this chunk would be added to the end of the existing text file)

---

```
-----BEGIN PRIVACY-ENHANCED MESSAGE-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
Content-Domain: RFC822
DEK-Info: DES-CBC,F8143EDE5960C597
Originator-ID-Symmetric: linn@zendia.enet.dec.com,,
Recipient-ID-Symmetric: linn@zendia.enet.dec.com,ptf-kmc,3
Key-Info: DES-ECB,RSA-MD2,9FD3AAD2F2691B9A,
          B70665BB9BF7CBCDA60195DB94F727D3
Recipient-ID-Symmetric: pem-dev@tis.com,ptf-kmc,4
Key-Info: DES-ECB,RSA-MD2,161A3F75DC82EF26,
         E2EF532C65CBCFF79F83A2658132DB47

LLrHB0eJzyhP+/fSStdW8okeEnv47jxe7SJ/iN72ohNcUk2jHEUSoH1nvNSIWL9M
8tEjmF/zxB+bATMtPjCUWbz8Lr9wloXIkjHUlBLpvXR0UrUzYbkNpk0agV2IzUpk
J6UiRRGcDSvzrsoK+oNvqu6z7Xs5Xfz5rDqUcMlK1Z6720dcBWGGsDLpTpSCnpot
dXd/H5LMDWnonNvPCwQUHt==
-----END PRIVACY-ENHANCED MESSAGE-----
```

Comment: ok so I have to convert the signature to base64 and then append a PEM header and footer and then this whole container should be appended to my text file right?

Comment: If you really want to replicate the defacto standard for this kind of stuff: http://wiki.samat.org/CheatSheet/OpenSSL would be a good start. Just replicate what OpenSSL does to achieve the same result.

Comment: how to extract base64 signature from the headers? How do I remove the BEGIN and END strings and get the signature within it? I am sure OpenSSL may have mentione this somewhere? any help?

Comment: Can I use some existing PEM_read_bio functions? Or should I do some string parsing myself?

Comment: I was thinking you would just do the basic string parsing yourself: text is simple enough to parse with strstr, strtok etc. and base64 is documented. Given you seem to be signing data directly using a private/public key rather than a certificate I was not considering actually using OpenSSL. I proposed the PEM format as the defacto standard for bundling crypto data with text documents.

Comment: should signatures be generally in plaintext? I thought we should also encrypt the signature...what can one typically with a signature? tampering it may only be fruitless as the verification will fail.well, still is it necessary to encrypt the signature itself?

Comment: Signatures are allowed to be in plaintext - with public key cryptography the the secret that needs to be protected is the private key.